# Check if file downloaded with DownloadManager still exist on device storage

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver, android-download-manager

I'm downloading all files in my application using DownloadManager. Also, I save all id's which enqueue method returns. The question is: How to determine is file still exist after some amount of time?

I'm trying to do this in that way

```
Cursor c =
        mgr.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(lastDownload));

if (c == null || !c.moveToFirst()) {
    // File doesn't exist?
}
```

But that didn't work. Sometimes downloadManager returns a Cursor and moveToFirst invocation return true but in fact, downloaded file was been deleted from a filesystem.

Okay, second way I found - obtain a content Uri from the download manager. Also, I'm reading [this post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) about content Uri limitations. If I understand correctly, in short - Uri doesn't guarantee that content exists, furthermore, Uri even doesn't guarantee that content IS A file. Anyway, I think that this construction should work:

```
try {
    contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(contentUri, "r");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // File doesn't exist?
}
```

But the result is very frustrating. Sometimes (absolutely random) application crash with SecurityException.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/1145 from pid=16585, uid=10086 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()
```

My questions are: How I can check if downloaded file exists? Why application crashes sometimes? It's looks like heisenbug because behavior is absolutely random.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add permission on your manifest for read or write file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or if you are working on version 23 then you should use security permission condition before fetching data.

Comment: Yep. This permission exist in my Manifest and runtime permissions check also implemented. Still no luck, application keep crashing (Storage permission is 100% granted).

Comment: You should Clean your project & try build it.